# Extract part of String using regex and assign it to variable scala

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

I have

```
val str = "abc:def"
val pattern = "(.*):.*".r
val prefix = str match {
  case pattern(prefix) => prefix
  case _ => ""
}
```

I want to avoid MatchError so if it matches I will return the match otherwise I will return "". This compiles and do extract "prefix = "abc". However I get a warning saying

> Suspicious shadowing by a Variable Pattern

IDE is suggesting putting `` around pattern(`prefix`).

Is there a better way of doing this? Why is the IDE suggesting that solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IDE shows the warning because you have 2 variables with the same name, I would suggest renaming the inner variable to something different:

```
val prefix = str match {
  case pattern(pref) => pref
  case _ => ""
}
```

The back ticks suggestion is not what you want in this case, you would use that if you wanted to match against the value of a variable (the IDE thinks you want that because `prefix` is the name of an existing variable).

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite it like below, using any other name for the prefix extracted from the pattern, because that value is then returned by the `match` and assigned to `prefix`

```
val str = "abc:def"
val pattern = "(.*):.*".r
val prefix = str match {
  case pattern(aaa) => aaa
  case _ => ""
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively,

```
scala> val prefix = pattern.unapplySeq(str).map(_.head).getOrElse("")
prefix: String = abc

scala> val prefix = pattern.findPrefixMatchOf(str).map(_.group(1)).getOrElse("")
prefix: String = abc
```

Avoids inventing names.